# Why it is not querying the database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I wrote the following code to retrieve data from the database

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'users';

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

// catch the values that are passed by the POST method
$courseId=$_POST["courseId"];
$hall=$_POST["hall"];
$day=$_POST["day"];
$year=$_POST["year"];
$time=$_POST["time"];

$statement=mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM Lectures WHERE day=? AND timeInterval=? AND courseId=? AND hall=? AND year=? ");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"sssss",$courseId,$hall,$day,$year,$time);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
// have to collect the results that are coming after the query is being executed
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);   //storing the results in a buffer for temporary
// now we need to bind the results
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$day,$time,$courseId,$hall,$year,$noStudents,$courseRefName,$courseRefTelNo,$lecturer);

// to send the data via JSON string
$lectureDetails=array();
mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement);

$lectureDetails["day"]=$day;
$lectureDetails["time"]=$time;
$lectureDetails["courseId"]=$courseId;
$lectureDetails["hall"]=$hall;
$lectureDetails["year"]=$year;
$lectureDetails["noStudents"]=$noStudents;
$lectureDetails["courseRefName"]=$courseRefName;
$lectureDetails["courseRefTelNo"]=$courseRefTelNo;
$lectureDetails["lecturer"]=$lecturer;

// data are stored in the array. now we need to send them via a JSON string
echo json_encode($lectureDetails);
// the java file that calls this method will receive echo
//The PHP json_encode function returns a string, containing the JSON equivalent of the values passed to it
//so in here $lectureDetails array is passed throught throughe JSON String.
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);  //closing the connection
mysqli_close($con);     //closing the sql connection

?>
```

according to the working fetching file as below(this returns values as expected)

```
<?php
//database connection
$host = 'localhost';
$user1 = 'root';
$password1 = '';
$database = 'users';

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user1, $password1, $database);


//checking the validity of the database
   // if(!$con){
    //die("connection Failed" . mysqli_connect_error());}
    //echo "connected Successfully";

$userName=$_POST["userName"];
$password=$_POST["password"];


$statement=mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM usersLogged WHERE userName=? AND password=?");
//to prevent from sql injection
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$userName,$password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

//after executing the command we will get all the results that were selected
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);   //storing the results in a buffer for temporary
//we need to bind the results
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userId, $userName, $firstName, $lastName, $password, $position,$birthDate,$qualification,$email);


//now we need to store them into an array inoder to send them via a JSON

$user=array();


mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement);
//fetch the result from a prepared statement into the variables bound by mysqli_stmt_bind_result. 
//Data are transferred unbuffered without calling mysqli_stmt_store_result() which can decrease performance (but reduces memory cost). 

//storing the values which are fetched from the database are kept in the array(#user)
$user["userName"]=$userName;
$user["firstName"]=$firstName; 
$user["lastName"]=$lastName;
$user["password"]=$password;
$user["position"]=$position;
$user["birthDate"]=$birthDate;
$user["qualification"]=$qualification;
$user["email"]=$email;

//now we need to pass the content to the phone,we send the array in a json

echo json_encode($user); // the java file that calls this method will receive echo
//The PHP json_encode function returns a string, containing the JSON equivalent of the values passed to it
//so in here $user array is passed throught the JSON String.
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con); 







?>
```

but the above `php` file is not fetching data from the `mysql` database.
I have created a `Lectures` table at the current `users` database and `day` `time` `courseId` `hall` `year` `courseRefName` and `lecuturer` are of String data type , `noStudents` and `courseRefTelNo` are of integer datatype.
Is there any mistake in the `mysqli_prepare` or in the way this is encoded to JSON, because Iam not getting any return from this (above) `php` file to my `java` in `android` application

Comment: check for Errors after executing query

Comment: In which platform you are using PHP, LAMP or WAMP

Comment: Do `var_dump(mysqli_stmt_execute($statement));` and see if it prints `bool(true)` if it doesnt then do `var_dump(mysqli_error($con));` and give us the result.

Comment: @Sathish Kumar D I am using  LAMP

Comment: execute the php file and update me the error report in the path var/log/apache2/error.log, Error shown with current time and date

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya are `timeInterval=? AND courseId=? AND hall=? AND year=?` they all strings? You are stating in your statement that their types are all strings. Anyhow you should really invoke a error handler

Comment: @Sathish Kumar D  here is the output that I get when above 2 `var_dump` commands are ran.

Comment: `string(0) ""
Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Timetable/test.php on line 20
NULL
Warning: mysqli_stmt_store_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Timetable/test.php on line 22

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Timetable/test.php on line 24`

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_stmt_fetch() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Timetable/test.php on line 28
{"day":"Mon","time":"08-10","courseId":"IS11206","hall":"NLH","year":"1","noStudents":null,"courseRefName":null,"courseRefTelNo":null,"lecturer":null}
Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Timetable/test.php on line 45
`

Comment: @isnisn yes they all are strings

Comment: @isnisn I have posted the out put of the above 2 `var_dump` commands, I get `string(0) "" ` from the first `var_dump(mysqli_error($con));` and `NULL` from `var_dump(mysqli_stmt_execute($statement));`

Comment: Have you checked that you are connected to the database?

Comment: @isnisn how to check that one

Comment: @isnisn Yes, it is connected i checked it through `if (!$con) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}`

Comment: Ah, you dont have those lines in your posted code above.

Comment: Have you tried omitting that last whitespace in `$statement=mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM Lectures WHERE day=? AND timeInterval=? AND courseId=? AND hall=? AND year=? ");` HERE: `AND year=? ");` after "?"... The reason you get those error messages is because there is something wrong with your query and therefore `mysqli_prepare` is failing.

Comment: problem with your connection string add the exception or condition to check "Is connection established or not?"

Comment: code you are given it's not have a password, are you put a paasword on the running file.???

Comment: @SathishKumarD I used this `if (!$con) { die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); }` command which was on the web, It gives me no error message, so it means that the Database connection is correct, isn't it, is there any other way to check the DB connection

Comment: @SathishKumarD No, I haven't used a password, the code which is used to `user` fetch data which I used to write this code (which gives errors) runs well and return results without any `password`. So this should too work :(

Comment: but i sure, statement is not prepared, There is a problem with this. check the query with simple query. like " select * from usersLogged"

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya The problem is still that your prepare is failing for some reason. Either you variables in the bind is empty/not set, or there is some character/blank space misspelling of table name or such. You could just set your variables to some bogus and try and se if the query still fails. If it doesnt, then you got a problem with your $_POST

Comment: @isnisn Thankyou very much, I found the problems,it is a mismatch between the data sent via `POST' and in the database had caused the problem. I have sent `time` in form of `08.00-10.00` and in database they were as `08-10` in form of 5 digits. My face became red once I saw that.

Comment: @SathishKumarD Thankyou for your support I have found the problem, it is mentioned in the above comment, thankyou all

Comment: Hehe, can happen to anyone. Im glad to help! Happy coding :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the mismatch between the data sent via `POST` and in the database had caused the problem. I have sent time in form of `08.00-10.00` and in database they were as `08-10` in form of 5 digits. So if anyone encounter problems like these be first check the data in the `database` and the values you passed through `POST` method